# What to do when a page is deleted for "reasons of moderation"

Tags: discussion, support

Firstly, I would like to know why [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486142/smallest-string-which-contains-all-27-combinations-of-1-2-and-3-as-sub) was deleted.
I feel the question was a good one, and I'm also sad to see my answer to it disappear.
I'm sure there was a good reason for deleting it, but I have no idea what that reason is.

This leads into my more general question, which is, what should a user of mathSE do if a question or answer they're following is deleted in this way?  I don't think that "nothing" is a reasonable answer here; users want to know why the question was deleted and if it will ever come back, and I would say they deserve to know.

I think the most common reason a question could be deleted "for reasons of moderation" would be that it is part of an ongoing contest or test.  But in this case, it should eventually return.  Is there any case where a question is deleted "for reasons of moderation" but never returns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The moderator message prepended to the question reads

> ***Moderator message:*** This question is a simple rephrasing of a current USAMTS competition question (question 1 from [this document](http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_25_1.pdf)).  Submission for the current round of the USAMTS competition are to be submitted by 12:00pm PST (UTC-8) on 15 October 2013; this question will therefore be restored on 16 October 2013.

So your answer will be restored on October 16.

In general, we will not delete good content. In fact, we have undeleted many questions that were deleted by the owner (whose answers have not yet been upvoted) because of this.

I am starting a discussion with the other moderators regarding what the best way to handle contest questions is. Since deleting a question makes it disappear for people under 10K or who don't have a link to the question, there is no way for them to see the moderator added message.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why I couldn't see the message.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How about answers that the owner deletes, but are good answers?

Comment: When we see them, we revive them, but the owner will know where those answers were. Since the main question was regarding an answer that went missing because its question had been deleted, I did not mention all cases.

Comment: As a non-moderator, I want to point out that this issue (what to do with live contest questions) has been discussed several times on thus meta. We hate to delete interesting questions, but we don't want to encourage cheating on competitions where time is of the essence. So deleting the question and renewing it when the contest is over allows people to answer it once the chance to cheat has passsed, and many see it as a reasonable compromise. The moderators should not be blamed to making the best of a bad situation.

Comment: Dear @robjohn, it is past  October 16, could the page be restored now?  Thanks